# Dropdownlist to change text field. Bootstrap Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm using a ajax call to populate my Select2 dropdownlist.
I want the choice made from dropdown to populate some fields with data from my database.
The text field should be editable and post new value to my database.
(Edit-database-form with jquery)
My problem is that i can´t get the text field populated.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="optionvalue" id="selectbox-o" class="col-sm-10" data-placeholder="Välj objekt..." />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="selectedID" placeholder="Alias" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var test = $('#selectbox-o');
$('#selectbox-o').select2({

    ajax: {
    url: "include/objekt.php",
    dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
            q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data };
        }
    } // Ajax Call
}); // Select2

// Start Change
$(test).change(function() {

    var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
    var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
    $('#selectedID').text(theID);
    $('#selectedText').text(theSelection);
}); //Change
}); //Domument Ready
```

Comment: open your debugging tools and check if any error occur? And put a console.log in ur change event and check if it did fire

Comment: If i use this line:    <p>Selected IDs: <span id="selectedID"></span></p>   It prints the choosen ID. But if i use the input text field it doesnt show... the code must be missing something?

Comment: try `$('#selectedID').val(theId);` since you say that using span it actually can display choosenID

Comment: I can't understand where your problem lies: is it that you can't detect the dropdown select change on your form, or that you can't set the values on your form from your code. With these kinds of problems you should break it down, test each process stand-alone, use your browsers console.log and debugger to step through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right JS code should be:

```
$('#selectedID').val(theId);
```

I changed .tex to .val and it worked!
Thanks –  Se0ng11